# How to Improve Code That Deletes Rows Below First Blank Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that works as intended, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to write it. Basically, this code searches for the word "Disbursements" and copies all of the rows with data below it, including the row with the specified word. After the rows are copied to a new sheet, the unnecessary rows below the contiguous range of data are deleted. In order to search for the last cell, I used a function that finds the last cell with data. Instead of deleting the rows below the contiguous range, should I just copy the contiguous rows to begin with? Is there a better way to delete the rows below the first blank row?

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

```
Sub Reformat_ZZ_CM_BNREG()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'declare variables to search for within bank register
Dim searchText As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim searchCell As Range
Dim newWS As Worksheet
Dim lastCell As String
Dim firstCell As String
Dim lastRow As Long


'set variables to sheet name, search text, and searchCell
searchText = "Disbursements"
Set ws = Sheets("ZZ_CM_BNREG")
lastCell = FindLast(3, "ZZ_CM_BNREG")
'Set lastCell = Range(Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlRows, xlPrevious, , , False), Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlColumns, xlPrevious, , , False))
Set newWS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("ZZ_CM_BNREG"))
newWS.Name = "Bank Register"

'Unmerge all cells in Column A & get cell address of searchCell
With ws

    ws.Activate
    
    Range("A:A").UnMerge
    
    Set searchCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Disbursements", _
        SearchFormat:=True)
    
    If searchCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Error")
    Else
        firstCell = searchCell.Address
    End If

End With

'copy range using above function to get last cell in range
'paste range onto the new sheet
'we are starting with the cell containing disbursements
ws.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Copy _
    Destination:=newWS.Range("A1")

DeleteRowsAndSheet

End Sub

Sub DeleteRowsAndSheet()

Dim LR As Long
LR = Sheets("Bank Register").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Sheets("Bank Register").Activate
Rows(LR + 1 & ":" & LR + 20).Delete

Sheets("Bank Register").Range("1:1").Delete

Sheets("ZZ_CM_BNREG").Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If the code works, then this question may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The issue is that I don't know if it's always going to work as intended, but I went ahead and uploaded it to the code review page. Thanks for the tip!